# Why isn't possible to make a sure profit from these bettings odds, even if the sum of their implied probabilities is less than 1?

Tags: probability, decision-theory, odds

I'm not familiar with betting, but I remember reading some time ago that, given the payoff odds of a bookmaker, the implied probabilities sum up to more than 1, and this [overround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_bookmaking#Making_a_.27book.27_.28and_the_notion_of_overround.29) guarantees a profit to the bookmaker, if she/he accepts bets in the correct proportion. By symmetry, I would expect that, if the implied probabilities sum to **less** than 1, then there must be a combination of bets which guarantees a sure profit to the bettor. I was really surprised, then, when a acquaintance of mine showed me the following odds on a event with two possible outcomes:

- Outcome $A$: 1/3
- Outcome $B$: 9/4

The outcomes are mutually exclusive. The sum of the implied probabilities is

$$p_1+p_2=\frac{1}{1+3}+\frac{9}{9+4}\approx 0.94$$

However, it seems to me that it's impossible to make a sure bet with these odds:
let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the amounts bet on $A$ and $B$, and $b_1$ (respectively $b_2$) the profit if $A$ (resp. $B$) happens. If I'm not mistaken, when the bettor wins, she/he gets the stake back. This means that $b_1$ and $b_2$ are given by

$$\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}=\mathbf{b}=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{3}x_1-x_2 \\ -x_1+\frac{9}{4}x_2}=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{3} & -1 \\ -1 &\frac{9}{4}}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$$

One can make a sure profit if and only if there exists a vector $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2)$ such that $b_1>0,\ b_2>0$. But such a vector cannot exist, because

$$\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\pmatrix{-\frac{4}{3} & -4 \\ -4 & -9}=\mathbf{M}$$

Since all components of $\mathbf{M}$ are negative, $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{M}\mathbf{b}$ has all negative components if $\mathbf{b}$ has positive components. But I cannot bet negative money :) Is this correct? Thus, is it false that if the sum of the implied probabilities is less than 1, then it is possible to make a sure bet?

Comment: You did it backwards. Your calculations are for odds of 3/1 and 4/9

Comment: @Hugh oh f...! Thus the correct implied probabilities are $\frac{3}{3+1}$ and $\frac{4}{9+4}$, whose sum is $\approx 1.058 >1 $, right?

Comment: @DeltalV that's correct. I always found the decimal odds system to be more straightforward